# Request al backend no funciona

Tags: java, angular, spring

Quiero realizar una llamada al BackEnd pero no funciona, retorna un Observable y jamás entra al map.
En el front tengo esta función

```
  needRefresh(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.http
    .get(
      this.config.getConfig("host") + "/login/renueva"
    ).pipe(
      map(response => {
      if (response.toString() === "true"){
        return true;
      } else{
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
```

Y este es el endpoint que tengo en el servidor

```
@GetMapping("/renueva")
   @ResponseBody
   public Boolean refreshToken (HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
       String auth = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
       final JWToken token = new JWToken(auth);
       return this.renewToken(token);
       
   }
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Es probable que estes recibiendo un error del backend, puedes poner el fragmento del codigo donde te suscribes al observable?

Comment: Simplemente estoy llamando al método en un if como IF (this.auth.needRefresh()). Está mal? @oscar_sls

Comment: No sabia que se podia usar angular en java?, corrijanme si estoy mal?, pero hasta donde se angular se usa es en Javascript, no en java.

Comment: @Riven Es el endpoint que tengo en el server, está en java.

Comment: Ok, tu no puedes hacer directamente needRefresh() en un if, si notas tu metodo needRefresh() retorna un observable al cual debes suscribirte para capturar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Retorna en tu servicio solo el observable

```
 needRefresh(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.config.getConfig('host') + '/login/renueva');
  }
```

Luego donde llamas la función needRefresh realiza la subscriptor (esto retorna una promesa donde puede resultar en éxito o error)

```
needRefresh().subscribe((response) =>{
    //Codigo de exito
},error=>{
   //codigo de error
})
```